# ajax Json Web Method with amcharts in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, json, ajax, amcharts, ammap

> Error: after calling the web method the map comes blank..NO map is
>   displaying in page

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>

       <link rel="stylesheet" href="ammap/ammap.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
     <script src="http://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/amcharts.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/pie.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/ammap_amcharts_extension.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://www.amcharts.com/lib/maps/js/worldLow.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script   src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.1.js" 
type="text/javascript"></script>    
    <script type="text/javascript">

            function createChart() {
                debugger;
                var chartData2 = [];
                var chartDataResults =[];
                $.ajax( {
                    type: 'POST',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    contentType: 'application/json',
                    url: 'AmGeochrt.aspx/GetDataonload',
                    data: {},
                    success: function( response ) {
                        var aData = response.d;
                        var id;
                        for ( var i = 0; i <=0; i++ ) {
                            var country = aData[i].costtype;
                            if (country = "cambodia")
                            {
                                id = "KH";
                            }

                                chartDataResults.push( {
                                "map": "worldLow",
                                "areas": [
                                  { "id": id, "color": "#00CC00" },
                                  { "id": "FR", "color": "#0000CC" }]


                            } );

                        }
                        // create the chart here
                        var map;
                        map = new AmCharts.AmMap();
                        map.pathToImages = "http://www.ammap.com/lib/images/";
                        var dataProvider = {
                            mapVar: AmCharts.maps.worldLow
                        };
                        map.areasSettings = {
                            unlistedAreasColor: "#DDDDDD",
                            rollOverOutlineColor: "#FFFFFF",
                            rollOverColor: "#CC0000"
                        };
                        map.backgroundColor = "#000000";
                        debugger;
                        map.dataProvider = chartDataResults;

                        // WRITE                                 
                        map.write("mapdiv");
                                           }
                } );
            }

            $( document ).ready( createChart );
    </script>

</head>
<body> 
   <div>
    <div id="mapdiv" style="width: 600px; height: 400px;"></div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>  
[WebMethod]
        public static List<ChartDetails> GetDataonload()
        {
            string Constring = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString2"].ConnectionString.ToString();
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(Constring))
            {
                string totaldata = string.Empty;
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select distinct countryname from [trackbycountry] where CountryCode in('cn','kh','my','Th','ID','VN','PH')", con);
               cmd.CommandTimeout = 50;
                con.Open();
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                //da.SelectCommand = cmd;
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                da.Fill(dt);
                con.Close();
                List<ChartDetails> dataList = new List<ChartDetails>();

                foreach (DataRow dtrow in dt.Rows)
                {
                    ChartDetails details = new ChartDetails();

                    SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("select costtype,totalcount from [trackbycountry] where countryname='" + dtrow[0].ToString() + "' and totalcount>1 order by costtype", con);
                    cmd.CommandTimeout = 50;
                    con.Open();
                    SqlDataAdapter da1 = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd1);
                    //da.SelectCommand = cmd;
                    DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
                    da1.Fill(dt1);
                    con.Close();
                    if (dt1.Rows.Count > 1)
                    {
                        foreach (DataRow dtrow1 in dt1.Rows)
                        {
                            //totaldata += dtrow1[0].ToString() + dtrow1[1].ToString() +"|";
                            totaldata += dtrow1[0].ToString() + ":" + dtrow1[1].ToString() + ",";
                        }
                        details.costtype = dtrow[0].ToString();
                        totaldata = "Country:" + dtrow[0].ToString() + "," + totaldata;
                        totaldata = totaldata.Substring(0, totaldata.Length - 1);
                        //string bal=totaldata.Replace("|", char(13)+char(10)");
                        details.costvalue = totaldata;
                        totaldata = "";
                        dataList.Add(details);
                    }

                }
                return dataList;
            }
        }

 class files for the web method
   public class ChartDetails   
        {
            public string costtype { get; set; }
            public string costvalue { get; set; }
        }
```

**Output**[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HRWOj.png

Comment: Are you sure you got something from the Ajax call? Maybe you can check the received data, i.e. `' success: function( response ) {
                        alert (response); ...`

Comment: i checked the country in alter(country); values are comming..but map is not comming can u please kindly go thru it.

Answer (score 0):

[image]Retrieving Data from database to JavaScript Maps in Amcharts using Asp,net, C#

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/ammap.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/maps/js/worldLow.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/themes/dark.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/serial.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/plugins/dataloader/dataloader.min.js"></script>
<script src="JSfiles/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
                 $.ajax({
                 type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                contentType: 'application/json',
                url: 'amchartGeoChart.aspx/GetDataonload',
                data:{},
                success:
                    function (response) {

                        drawVisualization(response.d);
                          }
            });
                 function drawVisualization(dataValues) {
                     var latlong = {};
                     latlong["AD"] = { "latitude": 42.5, "longitude": 1.5 };
                     latlong["AE"] = { "latitude": 24, "longitude": 54 };
                     latlong["AF"] = { "latitude": 33, "longitude": 65 };
                     latlong["AG"] = { "latitude": 17.05, "longitude": -61.8 };
                     latlong["AI"] = { "latitude": 18.25, "longitude": -63.1667 };
                     latlong["AL"] = { "latitude": 41, "longitude": 20 };
                     latlong["AM"] = { "latitude": 40, "longitude": 45 };
                     latlong["AN"] = { "latitude": 12.25, "longitude": -68.75 };
                     latlong["AO"] = { "latitude": -12.5, "longitude": 18.5 };
                     latlong["AP"] = { "latitude": 35, "longitude": 105 };
                     latlong["AQ"] = { "latitude": -90, "longitude": 0 };
                     latlong["AR"] = { "latitude": -34, "longitude": -64 };
                     latlong["AS"] = { "latitude": -14.3333, "longitude": -170 };
                     latlong["AT"] = { "latitude": 47.3333, "longitude": 13.3333 };
                     latlong["AU"] = { "latitude": -27, "longitude": 133 };
                     latlong["AW"] = { "latitude": 12.5, "longitude": -69.9667 };
                     latlong["AZ"] = { "latitude": 40.5, "longitude": 47.5 };
                     latlong["BA"] = { "latitude": 44, "longitude": 18 };
                     latlong["BB"] = { "latitude": 13.1667, "longitude": -59.5333 };
                     latlong["BD"] = { "latitude": 24, "longitude": 90 };
                     latlong["BE"] = { "latitude": 50.8333, "longitude": 4 };
                     latlong["BF"] = { "latitude": 13, "longitude": -2 };
                     latlong["BG"] = { "latitude": 43, "longitude": 25 };
                     latlong["BH"] = { "latitude": 26, "longitude": 50.55 };
                     latlong["BI"] = { "latitude": -3.5, "longitude": 30 };
                     latlong["BJ"] = { "latitude": 9.5, "longitude": 2.25 };
                     latlong["BM"] = { "latitude": 32.3333, "longitude": -64.75 };
                     latlong["BN"] = { "latitude": 4.5, "longitude": 114.6667 };
                     latlong["BO"] = { "latitude": -17, "longitude": -65 };
                     latlong["BR"] = { "latitude": -10, "longitude": -55 };
                     latlong["BS"] = { "latitude": 24.25, "longitude": -76 };
                     latlong["BT"] = { "latitude": 27.5, "longitude": 90.5 };
                     latlong["BV"] = { "latitude": -54.4333, "longitude": 3.4 };
                     latlong["BW"] = { "latitude": -22, "longitude": 24 };
                     latlong["BY"] = { "latitude": 53, "longitude": 28 };
                     latlong["BZ"] = { "latitude": 17.25, "longitude": -88.75 };
                     latlong["CA"] = { "latitude": 54, "longitude": -100 };
                     latlong["CC"] = { "latitude": -12.5, "longitude": 96.8333 };
                     latlong["CD"] = { "latitude": 0, "longitude": 25 };
                     latlong["CF"] = { "latitude": 7, "longitude": 21 };
                     latlong["CG"] = { "latitude": -1, "longitude": 15 };
                     latlong["CH"] = { "latitude": 47, "longitude": 8 };
                     latlong["CI"] = { "latitude": 8, "longitude": -5 };
                     latlong["CK"] = { "latitude": -21.2333, "longitude": -159.7667 };
                     latlong["CL"] = { "latitude": -30, "longitude": -71 };
                     latlong["CM"] = { "latitude": 6, "longitude": 12 };
                     latlong["CN"] = { "latitude": 35, "longitude": 105 };
                     latlong["CO"] = { "latitude": 4, "longitude": -72 };
                     latlong["CR"] = { "latitude": 10, "longitude": -84 };
                     latlong["CU"] = { "latitude": 21.5, "longitude": -80 };
                     latlong["CV"] = { "latitude": 16, "longitude": -24 };
                     latlong["CX"] = { "latitude": -10.5, "longitude": 105.6667 };
                     latlong["CY"] = { "latitude": 35, "longitude": 33 };
                     latlong["CZ"] = { "latitude": 49.75, "longitude": 15.5 };
                     latlong["DE"] = { "latitude": 51, "longitude": 9 };
                     latlong["DJ"] = { "latitude": 11.5, "longitude": 43 };
                     latlong["DK"] = { "latitude": 56, "longitude": 10 };
                     latlong["DM"] = { "latitude": 15.4167, "longitude": -61.3333 };
                     latlong["DO"] = { "latitude": 19, "longitude": -70.6667 };
                     latlong["DZ"] = { "latitude": 28, "longitude": 3 };
                     latlong["EC"] = { "latitude": -2, "longitude": -77.5 };
                     latlong["EE"] = { "latitude": 59, "longitude": 26 };
                     latlong["EG"] = { "latitude": 27, "longitude": 30 };
                     latlong["EH"] = { "latitude": 24.5, "longitude": -13 };
                     latlong["ER"] = { "latitude": 15, "longitude": 39 };
                     latlong["ES"] = { "latitude": 40, "longitude": -4 };
                     latlong["ET"] = { "latitude": 8, "longitude": 38 };
                     latlong["EU"] = { "latitude": 47, "longitude": 8 };
                     latlong["FI"] = { "latitude": 62, "longitude": 26 };
                     latlong["FJ"] = { "latitude": -18, "longitude": 175 };
                     latlong["FK"] = { "latitude": -51.75, "longitude": -59 };
                     latlong["FM"] = { "latitude": 6.9167, "longitude": 158.25 };
                     latlong["FO"] = { "latitude": 62, "longitude": -7 };
                     latlong["FR"] = { "latitude": 46, "longitude": 2 };
                     latlong["GA"] = { "latitude": -1, "longitude": 11.75 };
                     latlong["GB"] = { "latitude": 54, "longitude": -2 };
                     latlong["GD"] = { "latitude": 12.1167, "longitude": -61.6667 };
                     latlong["GE"] = { "latitude": 42, "longitude": 43.5 };
                     latlong["GF"] = { "latitude": 4, "longitude": -53 };
                     latlong["GH"] = { "latitude": 8, "longitude": -2 };
                     latlong["GI"] = { "latitude": 36.1833, "longitude": -5.3667 };
                     latlong["GL"] = { "latitude": 72, "longitude": -40 };
                     latlong["GM"] = { "latitude": 13.4667, "longitude": -16.5667 };
                     latlong["GN"] = { "latitude": 11, "longitude": -10 };
                     latlong["GP"] = { "latitude": 16.25, "longitude": -61.5833 };
                     latlong["GQ"] = { "latitude": 2, "longitude": 10 };
                     latlong["GR"] = { "latitude": 39, "longitude": 22 };
                     latlong["GS"] = { "latitude": -54.5, "longitude": -37 };
                     latlong["GT"] = { "latitude": 15.5, "longitude": -90.25 };
                     latlong["GU"] = { "latitude": 13.4667, "longitude": 144.7833 };
                     latlong["GW"] = { "latitude": 12, "longitude": -15 };
                     latlong["GY"] = { "latitude": 5, "longitude": -59 };
                     latlong["HK"] = { "latitude": 22.25, "longitude": 114.1667 };
                     latlong["HM"] = { "latitude": -53.1, "longitude": 72.5167 };
                     latlong["HN"] = { "latitude": 15, "longitude": -86.5 };
                     latlong["HR"] = { "latitude": 45.1667, "longitude": 15.5 };
                     latlong["HT"] = { "latitude": 19, "longitude": -72.4167 };
                     latlong["HU"] = { "latitude": 47, "longitude": 20 };
                     latlong["ID"] = { "latitude": -5, "longitude": 120 };
                     latlong["IE"] = { "latitude": 53, "longitude": -8 };
                     latlong["IL"] = { "latitude": 31.5, "longitude": 34.75 };
                     latlong["IN"] = { "latitude": 20, "longitude": 77 };
                     latlong["IO"] = { "latitude": -6, "longitude": 71.5 };
                     latlong["IQ"] = { "latitude": 33, "longitude": 44 };
                     latlong["IR"] = { "latitude": 32, "longitude": 53 };
                     latlong["IS"] = { "latitude": 65, "longitude": -18 };
                     latlong["IT"] = { "latitude": 42.8333, "longitude": 12.8333 };
                     latlong["JM"] = { "latitude": 18.25, "longitude": -77.5 };
                     latlong["JO"] = { "latitude": 31, "longitude": 36 };
                     latlong["JP"] = { "latitude": 36, "longitude": 138 };
                     latlong["KE"] = { "latitude": 1, "longitude": 38 };
                     latlong["KG"] = { "latitude": 41, "longitude": 75 };
                     latlong["KH"] = { "latitude": 13, "longitude": 105 };
                     latlong["KI"] = { "latitude": 1.4167, "longitude": 173 };
                     latlong["KM"] = { "latitude": -12.1667, "longitude": 44.25 };
                     latlong["KN"] = { "latitude": 17.3333, "longitude": -62.75 };
                     latlong["KP"] = { "latitude": 40, "longitude": 127 };
                     latlong["KR"] = { "latitude": 37, "longitude": 127.5 };
                     latlong["KW"] = { "latitude": 29.3375, "longitude": 47.6581 };
                     latlong["KY"] = { "latitude": 19.5, "longitude": -80.5 };
                     latlong["KZ"] = { "latitude": 48, "longitude": 68 };
                     latlong["LA"] = { "latitude": 18, "longitude": 105 };
                     latlong["LB"] = { "latitude": 33.8333, "longitude": 35.8333 };
                     latlong["LC"] = { "latitude": 13.8833, "longitude": -61.1333 };
                     latlong["LI"] = { "latitude": 47.1667, "longitude": 9.5333 };
                     latlong["LK"] = { "latitude": 7, "longitude": 81 };
                     latlong["LR"] = { "latitude": 6.5, "longitude": -9.5 };
                     latlong["LS"] = { "latitude": -29.5, "longitude": 28.5 };
                     latlong["LT"] = { "latitude": 55, "longitude": 24 };
                     latlong["LU"] = { "latitude": 49.75, "longitude": 6 };
                     latlong["LV"] = { "latitude": 57, "longitude": 25 };
                     latlong["LY"] = { "latitude": 25, "longitude": 17 };
                     latlong["MA"] = { "latitude": 32, "longitude": -5 };
                     latlong["MC"] = { "latitude": 43.7333, "longitude": 7.4 };
                     latlong["MD"] = { "latitude": 47, "longitude": 29 };
                     latlong["ME"] = { "latitude": 42.5, "longitude": 19.4 };
                     latlong["MG"] = { "latitude": -20, "longitude": 47 };
                     latlong["MH"] = { "latitude": 9, "longitude": 168 };
                     latlong["MK"] = { "latitude": 41.8333, "longitude": 22 };
                     latlong["ML"] = { "latitude": 17, "longitude": -4 };
                     latlong["MM"] = { "latitude": 22, "longitude": 98 };
                     latlong["MN"] = { "latitude": 46, "longitude": 105 };
                     latlong["MO"] = { "latitude": 22.1667, "longitude": 113.55 };
                     latlong["MP"] = { "latitude": 15.2, "longitude": 145.75 };
                     latlong["MQ"] = { "latitude": 14.6667, "longitude": -61 };
                     latlong["MR"] = { "latitude": 20, "longitude": -12 };
                     latlong["MS"] = { "latitude": 16.75, "longitude": -62.2 };
                     latlong["MT"] = { "latitude": 35.8333, "longitude": 14.5833 };
                     latlong["MU"] = { "latitude": -20.2833, "longitude": 57.55 };
                     latlong["MV"] = { "latitude": 3.25, "longitude": 73 };
                     latlong["MW"] = { "latitude": -13.5, "longitude": 34 };
                     latlong["MX"] = { "latitude": 23, "longitude": -102 };
                     latlong["MY"] = { "latitude": 2.5, "longitude": 112.5 };
                     latlong["MZ"] = { "latitude": -18.25, "longitude": 35 };
                     latlong["NA"] = { "latitude": -22, "longitude": 17 };
                     latlong["NC"] = { "latitude": -21.5, "longitude": 165.5 };
                     latlong["NE"] = { "latitude": 16, "longitude": 8 };
                     latlong["NF"] = { "latitude": -29.0333, "longitude": 167.95 };
                     latlong["NG"] = { "latitude": 10, "longitude": 8 };
                     latlong["NI"] = { "latitude": 13, "longitude": -85 };
                     latlong["NL"] = { "latitude": 52.5, "longitude": 5.75 };
                     latlong["NO"] = { "latitude": 62, "longitude": 10 };
                     latlong["NP"] = { "latitude": 28, "longitude": 84 };
                     latlong["NR"] = { "latitude": -0.5333, "longitude": 166.9167 };
                     latlong["NU"] = { "latitude": -19.0333, "longitude": -169.8667 };
                     latlong["NZ"] = { "latitude": -41, "longitude": 174 };
                     latlong["OM"] = { "latitude": 21, "longitude": 57 };
                     latlong["PA"] = { "latitude": 9, "longitude": -80 };
                     latlong["PE"] = { "latitude": -10, "longitude": -76 };
                     latlong["PF"] = { "latitude": -15, "longitude": -140 };
                     latlong["PG"] = { "latitude": -6, "longitude": 147 };
                     latlong["PH"] = { "latitude": 13, "longitude": 122 };
                     latlong["PK"] = { "latitude": 30, "longitude": 70 };
                     latlong["PL"] = { "latitude": 52, "longitude": 20 };
                     latlong["PM"] = { "latitude": 46.8333, "longitude": -56.3333 };
                     latlong["PR"] = { "latitude": 18.25, "longitude": -66.5 };
                     latlong["PS"] = { "latitude": 32, "longitude": 35.25 };
                     latlong["PT"] = { "latitude": 39.5, "longitude": -8 };
                     latlong["PW"] = { "latitude": 7.5, "longitude": 134.5 };
                     latlong["PY"] = { "latitude": -23, "longitude": -58 };
                     latlong["QA"] = { "latitude": 25.5, "longitude": 51.25 };
                     latlong["RE"] = { "latitude": -21.1, "longitude": 55.6 };
                     latlong["RO"] = { "latitude": 46, "longitude": 25 };
                     latlong["RS"] = { "latitude": 44, "longitude": 21 };
                     latlong["RU"] = { "latitude": 60, "longitude": 100 };
                     latlong["RW"] = { "latitude": -2, "longitude": 30 };
                     latlong["SA"] = { "latitude": 25, "longitude": 45 };
                     latlong["SB"] = { "latitude": -8, "longitude": 159 };
                     latlong["SC"] = { "latitude": -4.5833, "longitude": 55.6667 };
                     latlong["SD"] = { "latitude": 15, "longitude": 30 };
                     latlong["SE"] = { "latitude": 62, "longitude": 15 };
                     latlong["SG"] = { "latitude": 1.3667, "longitude": 103.8 };
                     latlong["SH"] = { "latitude": -15.9333, "longitude": -5.7 };
                     latlong["SI"] = { "latitude": 46, "longitude": 15 };
                     latlong["SJ"] = { "latitude": 78, "longitude": 20 };
                     latlong["SK"] = { "latitude": 48.6667, "longitude": 19.5 };
                     latlong["SL"] = { "latitude": 8.5, "longitude": -11.5 };
                     latlong["SM"] = { "latitude": 43.7667, "longitude": 12.4167 };
                     latlong["SN"] = { "latitude": 14, "longitude": -14 };
                     latlong["SO"] = { "latitude": 10, "longitude": 49 };
                     latlong["SR"] = { "latitude": 4, "longitude": -56 };
                     latlong["ST"] = { "latitude": 1, "longitude": 7 };
                     latlong["SV"] = { "latitude": 13.8333, "longitude": -88.9167 };
                     latlong["SY"] = { "latitude": 35, "longitude": 38 };
                     latlong["SZ"] = { "latitude": -26.5, "longitude": 31.5 };
                     latlong["TC"] = { "latitude": 21.75, "longitude": -71.5833 };
                     latlong["TD"] = { "latitude": 15, "longitude": 19 };
                     latlong["TF"] = { "latitude": -43, "longitude": 67 };
                     latlong["TG"] = { "latitude": 8, "longitude": 1.1667 };
                     latlong["TH"] = { "latitude": 15, "longitude": 100 };
                     latlong["TJ"] = { "latitude": 39, "longitude": 71 };
                     latlong["TK"] = { "latitude": -9, "longitude": -172 };
                     latlong["TM"] = { "latitude": 40, "longitude": 60 };
                     latlong["TN"] = { "latitude": 34, "longitude": 9 };
                     latlong["TO"] = { "latitude": -20, "longitude": -175 };
                     latlong["TR"] = { "latitude": 39, "longitude": 35 };
                     latlong["TT"] = { "latitude": 11, "longitude": -61 };
                     latlong["TV"] = { "latitude": -8, "longitude": 178 };
                     latlong["TW"] = { "latitude": 23.5, "longitude": 121 };
                     latlong["TZ"] = { "latitude": -6, "longitude": 35 };
                     latlong["UA"] = { "latitude": 49, "longitude": 32 };
                     latlong["UG"] = { "latitude": 1, "longitude": 32 };
                     latlong["UM"] = { "latitude": 19.2833, "longitude": 166.6 };
                     latlong["US"] = { "latitude": 38, "longitude": -97 };
                     latlong["UY"] = { "latitude": -33, "longitude": -56 };
                     latlong["UZ"] = { "latitude": 41, "longitude": 64 };
                     latlong["VA"] = { "latitude": 41.9, "longitude": 12.45 };
                     latlong["VC"] = { "latitude": 13.25, "longitude": -61.2 };
                     latlong["VE"] = { "latitude": 8, "longitude": -66 };
                     latlong["VG"] = { "latitude": 18.5, "longitude": -64.5 };
                     latlong["VI"] = { "latitude": 18.3333, "longitude": -64.8333 };
                     latlong["VN"] = { "latitude": 16, "longitude": 106 };
                     latlong["VU"] = { "latitude": -16, "longitude": 167 };
                     latlong["WF"] = { "latitude": -13.3, "longitude": -176.2 };
                     latlong["WS"] = { "latitude": -13.5833, "longitude": -172.3333 };
                     latlong["YE"] = { "latitude": 15, "longitude": 48 };
                     latlong["YT"] = { "latitude": -12.8333, "longitude": 45.1667 };
                     latlong["ZA"] = { "latitude": -29, "longitude": 24 };
                     latlong["ZM"] = { "latitude": -15, "longitude": 30 };
                     latlong["ZW"] = { "latitude": -20, "longitude": 30 };
                AmCharts.theme = AmCharts.themes.dark;
                window.map = new AmCharts.AmMap();
                window.map.addTitle("Traffic Geochart", 14);
                //window.map.addTitle("source: Gapminder", 11);
                window.map.areasSettings = {
                    unlistedAreasColor: "#000000",
                    unlistedAreasAlpha: 0.1
                };
                //window.map.imagesSettings.balloonText = "<span style='font-size:14px;'><b>[[title]]</b>: [[value]]</span>";
                var val = [];
                var dataProvider = {
                    mapVar: AmCharts.maps.worldLow,
                    images: []
                }

                for (var i = 0; i < dataValues.length; i++) {
                    var dataitem= dataValues[i];
                    var id = dataitem.CountryCode;
                    var costvalue = dataitem.costvalue;
                    var countryname=dataitem.costtype;
                    var icon = "M21.25,8.375V28h6.5V8.375H21.25zM12.25,28h6.5V4.125h-6.5V28zM3.25,28h6.5V12.625h-6.5V28z";
                   debugger;
                   dataProvider.images.push({

                                longitude: latlong[id].longitude,
                                latitude: latlong[id].latitude,
                                scale: 0.5,
                                svgPath: icon,
                                label: countryname,
                                color: "Green",
                                labelShiftY: 2,
                                zoomLevel: 5,
                                title: dataitem.costvalue,
                                description:"Welcome to Amcharts"

                                 });


                    window.map.dataProvider = dataProvider;
                    window.map.export = {
                        enabled: true
                    }
                    window.map.projection = "eckert6";
                    window.map.write("chartdiv");
                }

            }
        })
    </script>

C#
 [WebMethod]
        public static List<ChartDetails> GetDataonload()
        {
            string Constring = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString2"].ConnectionString.ToString();
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(Constring))
            {
                string totaldata = string.Empty;
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select distinct countryname from [trackbycountry] where CountryCode in('cn','kh','my','Th','ID','VN','PH')", con);
                //SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from [trackbycountry] where TotalCount > 100 order by countryName");
                cmd.CommandTimeout = 50;
                con.Open();
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                //da.SelectCommand = cmd;
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                da.Fill(dt);
                con.Close();
                List<ChartDetails> dataList = new List<ChartDetails>();

                foreach (DataRow dtrow in dt.Rows)
                {
                    ChartDetails details = new ChartDetails();

                    SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("select costtype,totalcount,CountryCode from [trackbycountry] where countryname='" + dtrow[0].ToString() + "' and totalcount>1 order by costtype", con);
                    cmd.CommandTimeout = 50;
                    con.Open();
                    SqlDataAdapter da1 = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd1);
                    //da.SelectCommand = cmd;
                    DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
                    da1.Fill(dt1);
                    con.Close();
                    if (dt1.Rows.Count > 1)
                    {
                        foreach (DataRow dtrow1 in dt1.Rows)
                        {
                            //totaldata += dtrow1[0].ToString() + dtrow1[1].ToString() +"|";
                            totaldata += dtrow1[0].ToString() + ":" + dtrow1[1].ToString() + ",";
                        }
                        details.costtype = dtrow[0].ToString();
                        totaldata = "Country:" + dtrow[0].ToString() + "," + totaldata;
                        totaldata = totaldata.Substring(0, totaldata.Length - 1);
                        //string bal=totaldata.Replace("|", char(13)+char(10)");
                        details.costvalue = totaldata;
                        details.CountryCode = dt1.Rows[0][2].ToString();
                        totaldata = "";
                        dataList.Add(details);
                    }

                }
                return dataList;
            }
        }
        public class ChartDetails
        {
            public string costtype { get; set; }
            public string costvalue { get; set; }
            public string CountryCode { get; set; }
        }
```